# Match dos contornos

Tags: imagem, arraylist, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, numpy

Criei o programa abaixo, para fazer a correção de provas.

https://gist.github.com/andreemidio/d2cdf3d301fd8df1677e9a315ff845f0

Eu consegui fazer os contornos, identificar os preenchimentos, preciso fazer o match das informações.

Cada linha me retorna 30 contornos retangulares, dos quais os preenchidos estão identificados. agora preciso saber a posição desses alveolos preenchidos dentro desse array.Para assim eu retornar a resposta da questão e a opção selecionada

O resultado para visualização é esse [image: gabarito processado]

Imagem a ser processada.[image: imagem a ser processada]

Creio que a questão do match das informações esteja nessa parte do código.

```
posicaoRespostas = np.empty(0,int)

for (q, i) in enumerate(np.arange(0, len(questionCnts), 30)):


    cnts = contours.sort_contours(questionCnts[i:i+30])[0]

    for (l ,k )in enumerate(cnts):
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(k)
        if (w >= 20 and h >= 20) and (w <= 25  and h <= 25) and ar >= 0.7 and ar <= 1.3:
            box = [(x//5)*5, y]
        #print(x, y)

        posicaoRespostas = np.append(posicaoRespostas,(l))

        cv2.rectangle(bolhas, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1) #desenho para visualização
```

Comment: Possui uma imagem do cartão resposta preenchido inteiro aleatoriamente?

Comment: Não ainda, pois nem esse estou conseguindo fazer a identificação, a segunda parte é fazer com as respostas aleatória. Esse template está ai, pois sei exatamente onde está as respostas e fica mais fácil de validar a saída.

Comment: Sim, as fotos que estão no post, são as que uso. A partir da segunda imagem do mural, chego na primeira imagem, no caso, já foi processada e retirada os contornos que preciso.

Comment: Para encontrar a posição destes contornos após o findcontour, veja esta [função do Opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html). Em que é possível verificar as coordenadas dos contornos encontrados. Mas seu programa está irreproduzível, sugiro criar um [mcve]

Comment: E você utiliza a função `findcontour` com a biblioteca bubbles, mas acho que a [Hough Circles](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) seria mais adequada. Em que a saída desta função já te daria as coordenadas de todos os círculos do caderno de respostas. Se o círculo estive preenchido corretamente, sugiro utilizar transformadas morfológicas para "desaparecer" com os círculos sem preenchimento e utilizar o Hough Circles para localizar o preenchimento das respostas.

Comment: Estou fazendo a alteração disso agora, estava fazendo um teste separado para ver como o Hough Circles se comporta na imagem, atualmente estou com errro de detecção de 10 contornos não encontrados.

Comment: Mas ainda fico com a dúvida, como foi fazer rastreio das informações, saber se a questão 1: A, está realmente marcada ??

Comment: Você já possui a coordenada do círculo, com isso você pode verificar se esta região de interesse (ROI) possui quantos pixels não brancos, se for um número de pixels maior do que a quantidade da maior letra (A,B,C,D,E), você sabe que esta posição é a marcada. Depois com a posição você sabe o número da questão e qual alternativa está assinalada.

Comment: Ok,vou tentar isso que falou, coloquei o código em um reposítório.
https://github.com/andreemidio/omr2